# Instagram Video API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, facebook-apps, facebook-permissions

We are already setup with API access to instagram functions like instagram_manage_comments, instagram_manage_insights. But with new function available to post videos, we want to use that.

The new permission is instagram_content_publish, see facebook description below:

> The instagram_content_publish permission allows your app to create organic feed photo and video posts on behalf of a business user.

How do we apply for this access, as facebook demands video to show how it will work and login so they can check it as well. But the problem is that we can't implement this API until permission is granted. Also our website  / facebook app is in Live Mode and we can't change it to development mode for obvious reasons.

Please advise how we can move forward with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a "test app" version of your live app where you can demo these new features without having to change the live app to development mode.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/test-apps/